# MySQL self-JOIN table

Tags: php, mysql, join, self-join

On my forum I use a database with a `posts` table :

[image]

- `type` can be a question, answer or note ('Q', 'A', 'N')
- `updated` is the date on which the post was last updated
- `postid` is an integer identifying the post
- `parentid` is an integer referring to the parent post (`NULL` for questions, refers to a question for answers, refers to a question or an answer for notes)

How do I create a table associating the `postid` of each question with the `postid` of the most recent answer/note associated with it?

I assume this requires a triple JOIN, but this is very new to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT
  p.postid,
  answersAndNotes.postid AS AnswerOrNoteId,
  answersAndNotes.updatedDate AS AnswerOrNoteUpdateDate
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT 
     parentid,
     postid,
     MAX(updated) AS updatedDate
   FROM posts
   WHERE `type` = 'A' OR `type` = 'N'
   GROUP BY postid
) AS answersAndNotes ON answersAndNotes.parentid = p.postid
WHERE p.type = 'Q';
```

The subquery:

```
  SELECT
     parentid,
     postid,
     MIN(updated) AS updatedDate
   FROM posts
   WHERE `type` = 'A' OR `type` = 'N'
   GROUP BY postid
```

Will give you those answers or notes and only the most recent ones, if there is a notetext or other columns you want to select add them to this subquery and to the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks a lot already, so far it does some good but results in duplicates. So when I try to add the result of the query to my new table (where `postid` is a `PRIMARY KEY`) it gives : *MySQL query error 1062: Duplicate entry '154' for key 'PRIMARY'*

Comment: @Bruno This error indicates that the values you are entering into the postid contains some duplicate values for 154, check your values again.